# Visual code unable to access SSH via private company network

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtual-machine, vpn

Is there any way to access our company network from VS code, we have a VM and I want to access to it via SSH. It is possible for me to access it using SSH tools like Putty, however this is not the case for VS code, in another way, is possible to me to access to a VM which is not connected to the private network.
I can't also download packages from terminal when I am connected to the private network of the company.

I am looking to see if there is a configuration in VS code or a specific port, so after change it I can solve this problem.